# Sitecore Federated Experience Manager:Access to FXM Module to a new user

Tags: sitecore, user-permissions, sitecore8, sitecore-fxm

How can I provide  access to FXM to a New User in Sitecore 8?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a role out of the box to enable this. You can create your own role which gives read permission to the FXM shortcut /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/marketing/federated experience manager.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but on doing this I am able to see the FXM Module however I dont see SAVE Option coming up on entering the site details in FXM dashboard.

Comment: Sorry i didnt have time to test it through, but the idea is the same. Enable all the things you need access to and assign those all to a role which you can add to users to enable the fxm functionality.